# How to realize right IEnumerator interface for multiple foreach?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, ienumerator

I have a code like:

```
        class T : IEnumerable, IEnumerator
        {
            private int position = -1;

            public T() { }

            public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() { return this; }

            public object Current { get { return position; } }

            public bool MoveNext()
            {
                position++;
                return (position < 5);
            }

            public void Reset() { position = -1; }
        }

//Using in code:
T t = new T();
foreach (int i in t)
 //to do something
```

In the code above all is working fine but when I use next:

```
foreach (int i in t)
   if (i == 2)
     foreach (int p in t)
       //print p
   else
       //print i
```

It prints (in brackets second loop): 0 1 (3 4) 2 instead of 0 1 (0 1 2 3 4) 2 3 4
I tested It on List and Collection and they do It right.
How can I to achive what I need?

Comment: Just as a side note: another way of showing that the current implementation is wrong: `Console.WriteLine(t.Count()); // 5 Console.WriteLine(t.Count()); // 0` i.e. it will ***only*** iterate a single time currently (note also that `Reset()` should never, ever, be used - it is formally deprecated and ***will*** intentionally  throw exceptions in most cases)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't because you have made your code surface a single enumerator, itself a mistake IMO. A  better version would be, for me:

```
class T : IEnumerable<int> {
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator() {
        int i = 0;
        while(i < 5) {
            yield return i;
            i++;
        }
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
}
```

The compiler will create the right devices to achieve this with separate enumerators.

Unless you are writing for .NET 1.1, then if you find yourself *manually* writing an enumarator, there's a very good chance that you are doing it the hard way, and getting it wrong as a bonus.

If you ***really must*** do it the hard way:

```
class T : IEnumerable<int>
{
    public T() { }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator() { return new TEnumerator(); }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
    private class TEnumerator : IEnumerator<int>
    {
        private int position = -1;
        public int Current { get { return position; } }
        object IEnumerator.Current { get { return Current; } }
        void IDisposable.Dispose() {}
        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            position++;
            return (position < 5);
        }
        public void Reset() { position = -1; }
    } 
}
```

The significance here is that different instances of `TEnumerator` allow the **same** `T` instance to be iterated separately.

Comment: @Praetor12 yes, but you would need a second type to represent the enumerator. I'll mock that up... 2 secs.

Comment: It seems this is a bit harder than I expect, but It is waht I need. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Praetor12 out of morbid curiosity, *why* do you need to write the enumerator the hard way?

Comment: I like to write code which works so as I understand. I don't know how exactly yeild works :( That is all.

Comment: @Praetor12 you might enjoy [Eric Lippert's blogpost series on Iterator Blocks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/iterators/) and more specifically the Raymond Chen blogposts and [Jon Skeet article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx) linked from [part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/13/iterator-blocks-part-two-why-no-ref-or-out-parameters.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

```
foreach (int i in t)
   if (i == 2)
     foreach (int p in t)
       //print p
   else
       //print i
```

First *always use braces*, while you indenting matches what will happen another `if` in there will confuse things.

```
foreach (int i in t) {
   if (i == 2) {
     foreach (int p in t) {
       //print p
      }
   } else {
       //print i
   }
 }
```

But you problem: you only have one counter per instance of `T`, and you are using the same instance. Therefore you do through once. If you want to allow concurrent enumerations the enumerator object will need to be separate with `GetEnumerator` returning a new instance each time.